# Output with multiple var

Tags: webpack

Do you think there is a way with Webpack to expose modules inside multiple `var`?

Let's consider I have the following input:

```js
const myLib = require('myLib');
const myOtherLib = require('myOtherLib');

export.modules = {
  myLib: myLib,
  myOtherLib: myOtherLib,
};
```

So I would've an output looking like:

```js
var myLib = (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) { ... })()

var myOtherLib = (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) { ... })()
```

All exported modules in my input file are exposed as `var` in the global output file scope. I have no idea how this output could be designed but that is the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`expose-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/) can do what you want. For example, running the following module through webpack:

```js
import myLibModule from 'expose-loader?exposes[]=myLib!myLib';
import myOtherLibModule from 'expose-loader?exposes[]=myOtherLib!myOtherLib';
```

will make the default export of `myLib` available under the global object (`global`, `window`, or `self`) as  `myLib` (and similarly for `myOtherLib`). The `import` identifiers (`myLibModule` and `myOtherLibModule`) don't matter to `expose-loader`.

Comment: Thanks for answering @arseneyr. I'll check.